# svn error while creating a tag

Tags: eclipse, svn, tags, subclipse

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: 
  svn: File not found: revision 2276, path '/mobilehollerweb/trunk/admin/mobilehollerweb/trunk/admin'
  svn: '/svn/venturedive/!svn/bc/2276/mobilehollerweb/trunk/admin' path not found: 404 Not Found (https://subversion.assembla.com)

org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: 
  svn: File not found: revision 2276, path '/mobilehollerweb/trunk/admin/mobilehollerweb/trunk/admin'
  svn: '/svn/venturedive/!svn/bc/2276/mobilehollerweb/trunk/admin' path not found: 404 Not Found (https://subversion.assembla.com)
```

I get this error when creating a tag for my code. We use assembla as our host and I use eclipse with subclipse plugin installed.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error message, it looks likes you're trying to run a command like:

```
svn copy https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/mobilehollerweb/trunk/admin /mobilehollerweb/trunk/admin -m "create a tag"
```

I think what you want is to do something like:

```
svn copy https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/mobilehollerweb/trunk/admin /mobilehollerweb/tags/admin/1.0 -m "create a tag"
```

SVN will not recursively create directories that aren't there-- the directory /tags/admin must already exist before the "1.0" tag can be created.